# Failure in increasing JVM heap memory by three different approaches in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I am running a 32 bit JVM on my system and I am using eclipse for java. I wrote a program to get the heap size as bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    System.out.println("current heap size:  " + heapSize / 1000000f + " m");

    long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    System.out.println("heapMaxsize:  " + heapMaxSize / 1000000f + " m");
    
    long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println("heap free size:  " + heapFreeSize / 1000000f + "m");
    
    System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    System.out.println("JVM is : " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
}
```

the result is as bellow:

```
current heap size:  259.52255 m
heapMaxsize:  1037.9592 m
heap free size:  258.0899 m
JVM is : 32
```

Now I need to increase my heap size memory because most of my programs are complaining about heap size memory. I tried 3 approaches to change and increase the heap size but I got failure:

I also should mention that the total memory of my computer is 8G and I can see from task manager that more than 70% of that is always in use.

**Approach one**> Java config > java > view >Runtime Parameters> setting this value: -Xmx3g      feedback: nothing

**Approach two**> Going to a specific program> Run COnfigurations>Arguments> -Xmx2048m    feedback:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

**Approach 3**> Eclipse> Windows> Preference> Java> Installed JREs> Edit> and in VM Arguments, I types: -Xms256M -Xmx2048M    feedback:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

**Question:** I don't know what else I can do and what should I try to increase my heap size?

Does the amount of in use memory which I explained is more that 70% always have any effect on heap?

Please help me!

Comment: You can directly set in environment variables with this property and it will applied to eclipse as well : 
_JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xms512m -Xmx2048m like this

Comment: Can't you upgrade to 64bit VM. 32Bit have limitations. http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

Comment: @Darshit how can I do it? I did that in appraoch3, didn't I?

Comment: @Reihan_amn Not in VM arguments. Add it in system variables.. Follow this link ... I think it can help you .. http://help.dugeo.com/m/faq/l/98932-how-do-i-edit-the-java-s-overriding-environment-variable

As well refer this link too : http://crunchify.com/increase-eclipse-memory-size-to-avoid-oom-on-startup/

Comment: @Darshit Thanks for the links. I currently don't have that variable. Should I add it?

Answer (score 3):

You are running the 32-bit version of the JVM.  To access significantly more memory you will need to switch to the 64-bit JVM.

From the [Oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit):

> **Why can't I get a larger heap with the 32-bit JVM?**
>
> The maximum theoretical heap limit for the 32-bit JVM is 4G. Due to various additional constraints such as available swap, kernel address space usage, memory fragmentation, and VM overhead, in practice the limit can be much lower. On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G. On 32-bit Solaris kernels the address space is limited to 2G. On 64-bit operating systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher, approaching 4G on many Solaris systems.

Comment: I upgrade to 64-bit JVM but still cannot reach out to 4G heap space. I also get a new issue about _Java_OPTIONS:

`current heap size:  514.8508 m`
`heapMaxsize:  1908.9326 m`
`heap free size:  509.4611 m`
`JVM is : 64`

`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx2048m`

Comment: Change to `-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m`

Comment: do you mean the default JRE argument or the _Java_Options?